# Drop Pandas columns with a high percentage of NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'val':[1,3,3,np.NaN,5,6,6,2],
                   'id':[1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3,np.NaN,3]})
df
```

I want to drop columns where the percentage of NaN values is over 50%. I could do it manually by running the following and then using drop.

```
df.isnull().sum()/len(df)*100
```

However, I was wondering if there was an elegant and quick code to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mean` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for remove columns:

```
print (df.isnull().mean() * 100)
group     0.0
id       62.5
val      12.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() <= .5]
print (df1)
  group  val
0     a  1.0
1     a  3.0
2     a  3.0
3     a  NaN
4     b  5.0
5     b  6.0
6     b  6.0
7     b  2.0
```

Answer (score 9):

Could use `thresh` param of dropna.

```
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=int(0.5*len(df)))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df.dropna(thresh=len(df)//2,axis=1)
Out[57]: 
  group  val
0     a  1.0
1     a  3.0
2     a  3.0
3     a  NaN
4     b  5.0
5     b  6.0
6     b  6.0
7     b  2.0
```